# Java : when is a variable de-referenced

Tags: java, memory, dereference

Looking to obtain some behind the scenes memory references and rules that Java follows.

Here is a snippet of code. 
Basically this class is used to instantiate some other object (MyOtherObject) after which reference to this objects doClose() method is sent to a Vector.

If 3 MyOtherObject objects are created, the Vector will have 3 entries.

A process will eventually be called causing the Listener to iterate through the Vector of MyOtherObject objects and call the doClose() for each one.

Currently the code shows

```
 myOtherObject = new myOtherObject();
```

as the active line. When this line is used, only 1 of the 3 MyOtherObject objects will actually be closed.

If the code is changed to be

```
   MyOtherObject myOtherObject = new MyOtherObject();
```

then each of the 3 MyOtherObject objects will get their doClose() routine called.

```
public class MyObject
{
    MyOtherObject myOtherObject ;

     public static MyObject getInstance()
     {
            :
            :
            :
         return instance;
     }

    public void runThis () 
    {

        ///MyOtherObject myOtherObject = new MyOtherObject(); //Works

        myOtherObject = new myOtherObject();  //Only closes one

        MyCustomObjectTracker customObjectTracker = new MyCustomObjectTracker()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void closingMyWindows()
                    {
                            myOtherObject.doClose();
                    }
                };

        refernceToSomeOtherObject.addMyObjectTracker(customObjectTracker);
    }
}
```

Since the variable in the "working" is local and won't be available for reference at a later time, does Java sort of replace the variable with the actual object reference at the time the variable goes out of scope?

In the "not working" scenario where only 1 gets closed, is this because the variable is an instance variable and when reference to the doClose() object is made it uses what ever reference happens to be in the myOtherObject variable at the time of execution for the doClose()?

Basically looking for what/when these object get de-referenced behind the scenes and if there is an official terminology for the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is not about dereferencing, I don't think. I think your confusion is about *closures*. When you make an anonymous class instance like you've done, you're making a closure, which does some magic call stack stuff to get the current state of local variables. Let's look at your working example first. (I've removed some of the bits not necessary to this explanation)

```
public class MyObject {
    public void runThis() {
        MyOtherObject myOtherObject = new MyOtherObject();
        MyCustomObjectTracker customObjectTracker = new MyCustomObjectTracker() {
            @Override
            public void closingMyWindows() {
                myOtherObject.doClose();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When you do `new MyCustomObjectTracker() { ... }`, the Java compiler sees that you use the variable `myOtherObject`, so it implicitly closes around that variable, remembering it for later. Note that the important thing here is that each time you call `runThis`, you're making a *new* local variable. It may have the same name as the old one, but you made a new local variable. So every `customObjectTracker` gets access to a *different* local variable. Hence, it all works out. Now, let's look at your other example.

```
public class MyObject {
    MyOtherObject myOtherObject;
    public void runThis() {
        myOtherObject = new MyOtherObject();
        MyCustomObjectTracker customObjectTracker = new MyCustomObjectTracker() {
            @Override
            public void closingMyWindows() {
                myOtherObject.doClose();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here, the code goes through the same rationale. We need to close around something called `myOtherObject`. But `myOtherObject` isn't a local variable; it's an instance variable. So really, we need to close around the object to which it belongs, which is `this`. Note that there's only one `this`. You can call `runThis` several times; you're only calling it on one object. So in this case, you're changing one variable several times and then making several new classes that all point to this one variable.

Anonymous classes are relatively easy to destructure into "real" classes by hand. So if the closures are confusing you, try to convert each of your code snippets into a form that doesn't use anonymous classes (so instead of `new MyCustomObjectTracker() { ... }`, make a new file with `class MySpecialCustomObjectTracker extends MyCustomObjectTracker`). Doing it this way will make you think about what state has to be passed to your new object, which is what the compiler does automatically when you make an anonymous class instance.

Comment: Thanks. Breaking out the class helps. There terminology "closure" is what I was looking for as well. Base on that, I searched for "closure" and found the following : "A closure is an anonymous function that ‘closes’ over its surrounding scope. Thus when the function defined by the closure is executed, it has access to all the local variables that were in scope when it was created."